# Google Chrome web page refresh broken

Tags: google-chrome, dojo

> Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.97 m

Many intranet web apps fail to load when hitting the "reload" button (or hitting F5) while in the app.

The page loads fine the first time, but it you are on the page and do a refresh, the page fails to load.

- This issue started with Chrome v48
- If you do a "hard refresh" (shift F5), page reloads fine
- If the server does not send 304 for javascript pages and is forced to send a 200 (no cache control), the page loads fine.
- All this works fine in other browsers
- Apps in question use the dojo javascript framework (an older version of it)

Since the initial load works fine, it seems to have something to do with the way Chrome handles the client cached javascript files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @GavinR There are JavaScript errors. The JavaScript files which the developer network panel says were not loaded since they weren't modified (304) act like they aren't available at all. None of the functions in these files are available and this causes JavaScript error downstream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've hit a bug in Chrome - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=570622

Basically, when Dojo does an XMLHttpRequest to load a module and the server responds with a 304, Chrome is passing back an empty response body rather than pulling the original response from the cache. Unsurprisingly, Dojo sees this as an error.

As you noted, forcing the server to do a full 200 response fixes the problem, I'm doing this with a bit of Apache HTTPD config to strip out the request header that triggers the 304 for my JavaScript files:

```
<LocationMatch "^/portal/static/.*\.js$">
    RequestHeader unset If-Modified-Since
</LocationMatch>
```

The Chromium issue already has a patch in it, so hopefully this will be fixed in the next Chrome release.

Comment: Great to know. Hope the fix gets pushed out soon. Thanks @Zorac

Comment: Version 48.0.2564.103 m is out and this issue is now fixed.